# Regex - Match characters but don't include within results

Tags: php, regex

I have got the following Regex, which ALMOST works...

```
(?:^https?:\/\/)(?:www|[a-z]+)\.([^.]+)
```

I need the result to be the only result, or within the same position in the Array.

So for example this `http://m.facebook.com/` matches perfect, there is only 1 group.

However, if I change it to `http://facebook.com/` then I get `com/`in place of where Facebook should be. So I need to have `(?:www|[a-z]+)` as an optional check really.

Edit:

What I expect is just to match `facebook`, if ANY of the strings are as follows:

> http://www.facebook.com
>
> http://facebook.com
>
> http://m.facebook.com

And obviously the **https** counterparts.

This is my Regex now

```
(?:^https?:\/\/)(?:www)?\.?([^.]+)
```

This is close, however it matches the **m** on when I try `http://m.facebook.com

https://regex101.com/r/GDapY5/1

Comment: You should specify what the regex should match in your example.

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin See update

Comment: You can try this regex, which works for all these strings. `https?:\/\/(?:[a-z]+\.)?(.*)\.`

Comment: Maybe make the `m.` part optional [`(?:^https?:\/\/)(?:\w+\.)?(\w+)\.com`](https://regex101.com/r/9UBW8L/1/)

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin spot on! make it an answer?

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin damn actually this doesn't work with **.co.uk**, ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could make the first `m.` part optional with `(?:\w+\.)?`.
Instead of a capturing group you could use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match.

Then match one or more word characters `\w+` and use a positive lookahead to assert that what follows is a dot `(?=\.)`

For example:

[`^https?://(?:www)?(?:\w+\.)?\K\w+(?=\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/Yvpflc/1/)

Edit: Or you could match for `m.` or `www.` using an alternation:

[`^https?://(?:m\.|www\.)?\K\w+(?=\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/eyDRg5/1/)

[Demo Php](https://3v4l.org/m3PHM)

Comment: So close, however fails on one of the links with **.co.uk**, see: https://regex101.com/r/Yvpflc/2

Comment: @MartynBall I have updated my answer with an approach using an alternation.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> So I need to have (?:www|[a-z]+) as an optional check really.

A `?` at the end of a pattern is generally used for "optional" bits -- it means "match zero or one" of that thing, so your subpattern would be something like this:

```
(?:www|[a-z]+)?
```

If you're simply trying to get the second level domain, I wouldn't bother with regex, because you'll be constantly adjusting it to handle special cases you come across. Just split on dots and take the penultimate value:

```
$domain = array_reverse(explode('.', parse_url($str)['host']))[1];
```

Or:

```
$domain = array_reverse(explode('.', parse_url($str, PHP_URL_HOST)))[1];
```

Comment: This still seems to struggle with **.co.uk**

Comment: You need to define your problem better. `m` and `www` are far from the only popular site prefixes. For example, what should `shop.foo.co.uk` and `shop.foo.co` return? Also note that letters are not the only valid domain name parts, so any regex that uses `[a-z]` is already not going to work in many cases.

Comment: IMO, in place of `parse_url($str)['host']`, it's better to use the second parameter (the component parameter) of `parse_url`: `parse_url($str, PHP_URL_HOST)`